# How do you server css files with express?

Tags: node.js, express

I have seen a lot of the similar questions but nothing I do seems to work. The css file isn't being served. I keep getting the following error.

> Refused to apply style from
>   'http://localhost:7000/public/css/styles.css' because its MIME type
>   ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME
>   checking is enabled.
>
> launch-analytics.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'parentNode' of undefined
>       at launch-analytics.js:4
>       at launch-analytics.js:5 (anonymous) @ launch-analytics.js:4 (anonymous) @ launch-analytics.js:5

my index.ejs file (path: user/Node/views/index.ejs)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/styles.css" type="text/css">
    <body>
        <p>I am the home page</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js file:(path: user/Node)

```
let express = require('express');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');

let app = express();

let urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })


app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static('/public'));

app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.render('index');
});

app.listen(7000);
```

The styles.css file:

```
body{
    background-color: skyblue;
    font-family: verdana;
    color: white;
    padding: 30px;
}
h2{
    font-size: 49px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    text-align: center;
}
p{
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
}
.text-field{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Why would `style.css` file MIME type be `text/html` ?

Comment: I have no idea. I specified it to be css.

Comment: Is the content of `style.css` valid CSS ? Not HTML ?

Comment: I suppose so. I added it above.

Comment: Try replacing `<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/styles.css" type="text/css">` by `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css">`

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work either :(

Comment: Did you try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54268605/can-node-presented-ejs-files-use-offline-bootstrap/54268941#54268941 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `app.use(express.static('/public'));` is pointing to directory relative to root dir. Change it to `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

Comment: Can you remove public from this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/styles.css" type="text/css">`

Comment: Do you mean remove the public directory?

Comment: doing so doesn't change anything.

Comment: Remove public from href

Comment: It worked when I used `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" type="text/css">` and `app.use('./public'));`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
app.use(express.static("/public"));
```

to this

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

Also answered here: [Express-js can't GET my static files, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924072/express-js-cant-get-my-static-files-why)